# R qqplotr Confidence Intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I want to plot the 95% confidence intervals of a variable vs variable QQplot in R using the package [qqplotr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qqplotr/vignettes/introduction.html). I can plot the data but can't figure out how to calculate the confidence intervals.

This is my code:

```
qqplot(VAR_A, VAR_B, xlim = c(10, 35), ylim = c(10, 35), 
   xlab = "Var_A", ylab = "Var_B")
abline(a = 0, b = 1)
```

This is the output:
[QQplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYpL2.png)

This is a code example from the qqplotr manual using a single variable:

```
ggplot(data = smp, mapping = aes(sample = norm)) +
stat_qq_band(bandType = "boot", mapping = aes(fill = "Bootstrap"), alpha = 0.5)) +
stat_qq_line() +
stat_qq_point() +
labs(x = "Theoretical Quantiles", y = "Sample Quantiles")
```

Can somebody please show me how I can plot two variables as a QQplot with the confidence interval?

Comment: This isn't making a lot of sense. QQ-plots don't usually have confidence intervals and can you describe exactly what you expect to see with two variables on one QQ-plot?

Comment: Have you checked out the package qqplotr? I want to compare distributions for ANY change. This is quite frequently done in my field this way, I just can't get my head around the R code.